# if ID does not match x or children of x

Tags: jquery

I have a div with an id and I also have a piece of jQuery code to detect if the relatedTarget's id does not match the divs id. This itself works fine, but I also don't want it to match any children of said div either.

The HTML is similar as follows...

```
    <div id="a">
        <div id="b">
            <img src="..." />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jQuery code is similar as follows...

```
    if(e.relatedTarget.prop('id') != 'a') {
```

Of course the if statement will return true if the relatedTarget points to children of div#a which is not what I want.

Any ideas how I would go about fixing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if($(e.relatedTarget).closest('#a').length == 0) {
```